# Orientation Changes

Tags: android-orientation

Is there any way to change orientation landscape directly? I need to open a screen in landscape mode directly when i am in portrait screen. I have a code for this below

```
int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

       System.out.println(i);
       i++;
    }
    else {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
       System.out.println(i);
       i++;
    }
```

This code working fine, but whenever i try open in landscape on portrait screen it will automatically call first portrait and then it will open in landscape.

Any one suggest is there any way to ignore this case?

Comment: Specify the preferred orientation in the android manifest for each activity.

Comment: I need once again come back to portrait, thats why?

Comment: You can set the preferred orientation to landscape and the activity will open in landscape. If you need to change it again later you can do it with your code.